# NetCDF4 Python not recognizing attributes

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I am running the following code:

```
file = Dataset('file.nc')
print(file.ncattrs())
for name in file.ncattrs():
 print(name)
```

The second line returns [], and the for loops returns nothing, suggesting there are no attributes in the file. However, I opened the file and found 41 global attributes. Why is this not detecting the attributes?

EDIT: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PiGDYJ9_oQtS2io6hgbUb7BeDVu8ILZC) is the file I'm using.

Comment: That should indeed work (just tested it). Can you share the NetCDF file?

Comment: I opened your file, and get: `'title', 'data_product_type', 'source', 'mission', ...` if I print the `ncattrs()`. That makes it difficult to solve this problem, as it isn't reproducible on other systems...

Comment: I ran it again in a new python file, and it worked flawlessly. I'm not sure why it didn't work before, but it does now.